# addEventListener syntax with variable function name

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, addeventlistener

In my Firefox extension, I create a popup menu dynamically.  Originally, I used this line on each menu item:

`menuFunc.setAttribute("oncommand","MainExtension.MyPlugin." + functionName + "();");`

where `functionName` is a string with the name of the function to be called for that menu item.  This worked fine.  When I uploaded my extension to the Mozilla Addons page, the automated code validation program flagged this line and said that using setAttribute to set oncommand in this way was not secure and that addEventListener should be used instead.  I switched to this syntax:

`menuFunc.addEventListener("oncommand",function() {MainExtension.MyPlugin[functionName]},false);`

but now nothing happens when I click on a menu item.

Is my syntax off or is there something else wrong?  I don't think the problem is the common 'this' reference error.  I tried removing all uses of 'this' from one of the functions and it still did not work.  It seems like the functions are not being called at all.  No errors are being generated either.

Comment: Should 'oncommand' not be 'command' when using addEventListener we usually drop the 'on' prefix.

Comment: Hmmm, that might be one problem with the code, but still nothing is happening after I change "oncommand" to "command".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

The `command` action is attached using just `command`, not `oncommand`:

```
menuFunc.addEventListener("command", MainExtension.MyPlugin[functionName], false);
```

---

You should be able to just do:

```
menuFunc.oncommand = MainExtension.MyPlugin[functionName];
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either, which is weird since it seems so close to the `setAttribute` version.

Comment: Can you check if the function exists? `console.log(typeof MainExtension.MyPlugin[functionName]);`

Comment: That gives me "function", so it seems like the function exists.

Comment: Yes, switching "oncommand" to "command" was the answer.  Initially, this didn't help me, either because I had a 'this' in my function or I had the wrong syntax in my function call.  In my question above, I have `menuFunc.addEventListener("oncommand",function() {MainExtension.MyPlugin[functionName]},false);`.  I should have had `menuFunc.addEventListener("oncommand",function() {MainExtension.MyPlugin[functionName]();},false);`.  This latter syntax (with the parentheses and semicolon) works for me, as does your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Does it help to use `true` instead of `false` as the third parameter in order to capture the event?

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to help : /